# C# Return match found with Contains

Tags: c#, linq

I need to return all matches found when comparing a block of text with a list of strings.

```
if(myList.Any(myText.Contains))
```

I can verify that there is a match with the above, but I'm not sure how to go further and return the matching string. I looked into Intersect, but as far as I understood it only works on two of the same type.

Sample data:

```
myList[] = { "City of London", "City of Edinburgh" }; etc
myText = "I am applying for the position in the City of London";
```

The desired result here would be "City of London", either via setting the resulting match as a string, or returning the index of myList. Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "City Of London" is not a deterministic match in "I am applying for the position in London"

Comment: re @Agalo, I've edited my question to reflect that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        myList.Add("City of London");
        myList.Add("City of Edinburgh"); 
        string myText = "I am applying for the position in the City of London";

        var result = myList.Where(x => myText.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, seems to do the trick. In order to check result as a string I added:     string match = string.Join(",", result.ToArray());

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string result= myList.FindAll(x=> myText.IndexOf(x)>-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = myList.Where(a => myText.IndexOf(a) > 0).ToList();
```